# First argument of ternary must be Boolean: String

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to use ternary operator in apex.i want to check not null for date field

here is my code
`(list[j-1].EDI_StartDate__c != null) ? list[j-1].EDI_StartDate__c.format() : ''`

i am getting a compile time error as First argument of ternary must be Boolean: String.

Please help me to resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to write your condition inside open `(` and close `)` bracket

```
(list[j-1].EDI_StartDate__c != null ? list[j-1].EDI_StartDate__c.format() : '')
```